# NodeJS equivalent of C binary write

Tags: c, arrays, node.js, binary, fwrite

I have this C code to dump an array into a binary file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Person {
    char name[256];
    double num1;
    double num2;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    struct Person ary[2];

    strcpy(ary[0].name, "john");
    ary[0].num1 = 25;
    ary[0].num2 = 50;

    strcpy(ary[1].name, "jane");
    ary[1].num1 = 100;
    ary[1].num2 = 200;

    FILE *out = fopen("test.dat", "w+b");

    fwrite(ary, sizeof(ary), 1, out);
    fclose(out);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to dump an array of objects or array of strings and numbers into a binary file in NodeJs.

Sample arrays:

```
var ary1 = [100, 2000, 50, 20000, 300, 8000];  // <<< this one I can do

var ary2 = ['John', 'jane', 'jim', 'joe']; // <<< not sure about this one

// this is what I ultimately want to write to binary file
var ary3 = [
  ['john', 25, 50],
  ['jane', 100, 200]
];
```

Keep in mind we want to write in binary to create smaller data files.
Writing everything as string is simple but that's not what I need.

My example doesn't illustrate it, but when I have to write millions of integers and floats, binary data comes in handy.

Here's my nodejs code to write simple number array:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var ary = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    ary.push(i * 100000);
}

var str = JSON.stringify(ary);

fs.writeFileSync('test.txt', str);

var fd = fs.openSync('test.dat', 'w');

var buff = new Buffer(ary);

fs.write(fd, buff, 0, buff.length, 0, function(err, written) {
    console.log('err', err);
    console.log('written', written);
});
```

The code above creates two files:
test.txt should have a size of 8886 bytes while
test.dat should have a size of 1000 bytes.

It would be nice if I can write ary2 or ary3 to binary file.

Thanks

**UPDATE: Fix code to write correct data to buffer and binary file**

var buff = new Buffer(ary) will create an Uint8 array.  The max value for Uint8 is 255.  This forces all values above 255 to be x MOD 256.

Here's the new code:

```
var fs = require('fs');

// This block writes the values into the buffer
// 1000 elements times 4 bytes per element for 
var length = 1000;
var buff = new Buffer(length * 4);
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    buff.writeUInt32LE(i * 100000, i * 4);
}

var fd = fs.openSync('test.dat', 'w');
fs.write(fd, buff, 0, buff.length, 0, function(err, written) {
    console.log('err', err);
    console.log('written', written);
});
```

This should create a binary file with 4000 bytes.  A less disappointing than 1000, but it will store the correct data.

Comment: is base64 encoding out of scope?

Comment: @FredMaggiowski - base64 helps but still not the optimum.

Comment: I imagined :) I'm thinking about it and let you know if something comes to mind!

Comment: FYI, I'm current writing different parts to the file so I'll at least compress the number array portion to be much smaller while still saving the text portion as strings.

Comment: What is the largest possible value of num1 and num2? Are there more small numbers than large numbers?

Comment: It's a wide range, I'm using Uint32 in my example but in my actual project, I have to use Float32.